# Старый и новый switch

Tags: java, switch

я пишу метод преобразования римских цифр в арабские с помощью switch. вот небольшие примеры с новым и старым switch соотвественно:
Новый:

```
public static int getArabic(char romanChar) {
        return switch (romanChar) {
            case 'M' -> 1000;
            case 'D' -> 500;
      default -> 0;
        };
}
```

Старый:

```
public static int getArabic(char romanChar) {
    
        return switch (romanChar) {
            case 'M' :
               1000;
                break;
            case 'D':
                500;
                break;

            default: 0;
        };
```

Как новый switch переписать на старый (я пытался вводить общую int переменную, но он всё равно продолжает ругаться на break)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
public static int getArabic(char romanChar) {
    switch (romanChar) {
        case 'M': return 1000;
        case 'D': return 500;
        default: return 0;
    }
}
```